# My products aren't showing up on my new store. Transactional website needs to share all the same products as default store

Tags: catalog, products, category-products, ee-1.13.1.0

System > Manage Stores

Name, code, website are unique but it's going to share Root Category > Default Category.

System > Configuration > Web

All the URL's have been configured to point at the correct store. The website and all it's styles are populating. Just no products.

Catalog > Manage Products

I selected all and used the action dropdown to "update attributes". Hit submit. Then Websites left submenu > add product to websites. I select my new store and hit save.

I've ensured that all these products are enabled and have qty's associated with them and they have visibility correct.

Next, in SSH i ran php reindexer.php --reindexall

Magento ver. 1.13.1.0

Why are my products showing up? Is there something that i missed?